# How to delete not duplicated rows of 2 tables that only 2 columns of them compare for duplication in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want a stored procedure to create a temptable based on 2 columns of `table_A`, and then check if there are rows in `table_B` (with 5 columns) that have these 2 columns like the way they are in `table_A`. Don't do anything to them a delete rows that are not duplicate.

Something like this:

```
Create Procedure DeleteExtra

as

Create Table #TempTotalHoney
(
HarvestDate Date,
HoneyType VarChar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTotalHoney
Select HarvestDate, HoneyType
From tHoneyHarvest
Group BY HarvestDate, HoneyType

//until here temptable created as I want, but I don't know how to check
//not duplicated rows, I tried this But it is wrong...

Delete From tHoneyWeight
Where HarvestDate AND HoneyType Not in (select HarvestDate, HoneyType 
From #TempTotalHoney)

//must check these tow columns together not separately  


If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTotalHoney') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #TempTotalHoney
End
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeleteExtra, Line 17
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

**Update:**

```
this is #TempTotalHoney that created from table_A

HarvestDate           HoneyType
---------------------------------------------------
2017-01-10            Pure
2017-01-10            Semi-Pure
2017-02-03            Pure
2017-02-04            artificial
```

and

```
table_B:

RecID      HarvestDate    HoneyType   TotalCombs    TotalWeight
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1         2017-01-10     Pure            10           22
 3         2017-01-10     Semi-Pure       11           24
 4         2017-02-03     Pure            22           50
 6         2017-02-04     artificial      25           56
 8         2017-01-10     Semi-Art        10           18.5
 9         2017-02-05     Pure            11           19
```

I want the RecID 8 and 9 that combination of HarvestDate And HoneyType of them not exists in #TempTotalHoney be deleted.

Comment: Kindly provide some sample data and expected result from that sample data.

Comment: @Viki888 can you explain it a little more or if it possible post it as an answer?

Comment: Provide some sample data in `table_A`, `table_B` and provide the result you want from that sample data

Comment: @Viki888 I updated the question

Comment: So do you want to delete `RecID 18 and 19` from `table_B`?

Comment: @Viki888 Yes RecID 8 and 9, but I don't know the exact RecID cause Table_B repeatedly edited by user and RecID is PK and auto increment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134577/discussion-between-viki888-and-saranio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using below query

```
DELETE table_B
FROM table_B B
 LEFT JOIN #TempTotalHoney A 
  ON B.HarvestDate = A.HarvestDate 
   AND B.HoneyType = A.HoneyType
WHERE A.HoneyType is Null;
```

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: tanks, I get this error:
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Arabic_CI_AS" and "Arabic_100_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

Comment: You seems to have a collation problem. Modify the `AND` condition like `AND B.HoneyType = A.HoneyType COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS`

Comment: yeeees, thanks a a lot, finally problem solved, I asked a question and because it remained unanswered I had to solve it with other solution and that caused me this problem that you just solved it.

do you have time to take a look at that and see is there a better way?

Comment: Is this your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934441/how-to-prevent-duplicate-update-in-sql-stored-procedure you are talking about?

Comment: ok intimate me when you are done. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134577/discussion-between-viki888-and-saranio